# Convert string to Uri string

Tags: android, uri

I have a problem. I convert a string to Uri but it doesn't passes it all.

```
String num = "*#123#";
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + num));
startActivity(call);
```

After parse it I get ' * ' instead of " *#123# ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

# is not well recognized in Uri, but you can replace sharp by it's uri representation `%23` :

```
String num = "*%23123%23";
```

Or, you can do (better but a little more complicated) :

```
String num = "*".concat(Uri.encode("#")).concat("123").concat(Uri.encode("#"))
```

Comment: Thanks man! Can you tell me where can I learn more about that?

Comment: You can read the URL Encoding reference from W3School : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Nice! Thanks, you were very helpful!